# Add Class Once Another Class is Added

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I am using a Framework 7 to develop a web app, and in it, I have it so the menu is a left panel that opens from a menu button. When the menu is open, the body has the class .with-panel-left-cover. I have been trying to add a class to another part of the document when this occurs, so I can add styling. Below is the code and what I am trying to use right now.

```
if ( $('body').hasClass('with-panel-left-cover') ) {
     $('.views').addClass( "overlay" );
}
```

And the html (with filler text)

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <title>My App</title>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links/font-awesome-4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
    <!-- Path to your custom app styles-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="links/css/my-app.css">
    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="statusbar-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Panels overlay-->
    <div class="panel-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Left panel with reveal effect-->
    <div class="panel panel-left panel-cover" style="background:lightgray">
      <div class="content-block">
         <p> <a class="button button-big color-blue button-fill panel-close" href="#index"><i class="fa fa-home fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Step 1</a> </p> 
          <p> <a class="button button-fill button-big panel-close" href="#about"><i class="fa fa-info fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Step 2/a> </p>
         <p> <a class="button button-fill button-big panel-close" href="#form"><i class="fa fa-file fa-lg fa-fw"></i> Step 3</a> </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    <!-- Views-->
    <div class="views">
      <!-- Your main view, should have "view-main" class-->
      <div class="view view-main">
        <!-- Top Navbar-->
        <div class="navbar">
          <!-- Navbar inner for Index page-->
          <div data-page="index" class="navbar-inner" style="background-color:white">
            <!-- We have home navbar without left link-->
            <div class="center sliding"><strong>Phone App</strong></div>
            <div class="right">
              <!-- Right link contains only icon - additional "icon-only" class--><a href="#" class="link icon-only open-panel"> <i class="icon icon-bars"></i></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Navbar inner for About page-->
          <div data-page="about" class="navbar-inner cached">
            <div class="left sliding"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
            <div class="center sliding"><strong>How it works</strong></div>
          </div>
          <!-- Navbar inner for Services page-->
          <div data-page="services" class="navbar-inner cached">
            <div class="left sliding"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
            <div class="center sliding">Services</div>
          </div>
          <!-- Navbar inner for Form page-->
          <div data-page="form" class="navbar-inner cached">
            <div class="left sliding"><a href="#" class="back link"> <i class="icon icon-back"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
            <div class="center sliding"><strong>Submissions</strong></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Pages, because we need fixed-through navbar and toolbar, it has additional appropriate classes-->
        <div class="pages navbar-through toolbar-through">
          <!-- Index Page-->
          <div data-page="index" class="page">
            <!-- Scrollable page content-->
            <div class="page-content" style="background-color: #ed1c24" >
                <img src="images/Filler.png" alt="" class="ri">
                <!--<h1 style="font-size: 3em;
                color: ghostwhite;
                text-shadow: red -2px -1px 1px;"> Flash <i class="fa fa-bolt" style="color: white; text-shadow: yellow -1px 2px 25px;"></i> News </h1>
                <h2 style="color:ghostwhite;text-shadow: red -2px -1px 1px;">Please swipe to the right or use the above button to navigate the app!</h2>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- About Page-->
          <div data-page="about" class="page cached">
            <div class="page-content" style="padding-top:0px; padding-bottom:0px">
              <div class="content-block" style="padding:0; margin:0px">
              <div class="content-block-title"></div>

            <div class="one" style="background-image:url(images/8-People.jpg); background-size: cover; height:66vh"> 
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Filler</div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-content-inner">
                        Filler
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
             </div>

             <div class="two" style="background-image:url(images/12370-NOAIKP.jpg); background-size: cover; height:66vh"> 
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Filler</div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-content-inner">
                        Filler
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

             <div class="three" style="background-image:url(images/10895-NN6QH9.jpg); background-size: cover; height:66vh"> 
                <div class="card">
                  <div class="card-header">Filler</div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-content-inner">
                        Filler
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
               </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <!-- Form Page-->
                    <div data-page="form" class="page cached">
            <div class="page-content">
            <iframe src="http://www.filler.com" style="width: 100%;height: 100%;border: 0;"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Bottom Toolbar-->

      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to your app js-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="links/js/my-app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ? You haven't asked a question.

Comment: Why do you need to use another class on the child element? Just use a CSS selector keyed on the class of the body, eg `body.with-panel-left-cover .views { /* rules... */ }`

Comment: Well, I had over complicated that a bit. Thanks for the help Rory, that worked great!